# How to determine if a given path is a file or folder?

Tags: javascript, filepath, windows-scripting

what is the simplest way to determine if a given path is a folder or file using Jscript?

Comment: A path like `/usr/local/bla` could be a file or a folder, so it isn't generally possible, unless you have some constraints to distinguish files and folders by.

Comment: `/folder/a`, is that folder named `a` or a file named `a` ?

Comment: Are you talking about Javascript in a browser, in which case the paths would be URLs, or Javascript in some other environment that has access to a filesystem?

Comment: no.. I am not talking abt Jscript in a browser.

Comment: @sw so your question makes zero sense, because JavaScript is client side language that run inside a browser. Please explain better what you want and retag the question with proper tags.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: bullshit. @svv’s question makes perfect sense: `JScript` is Microsoft’s Javascript implementation, which runs within Windows Scripting and ASP servers as well as in the IE browser.  There's dozens of Javascript implementations outside of browsers.

Comment: @Mart JScript and JavaScript are two different things and we do have JScript tag here. I am aware of JScript but I'm also aware that it's **not** JavaScript, even if it has some common features and syntax.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I added the JScript tag only. But each time it is changing into Javascript. That is why u can see Jscript at the end of the question Btw.. even Javascript can also be used outside browser.

Comment: @Alex, Is it possible in windows to have a file and folder with same name? I tried creating but it is not allowing. so, I guess it is not possible. Pl correct me if wrong

Comment: @svv Maybe not, but still, it wouldn't matter if trying to determine it from a string.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: like I said: JScript is Microsoft’s Javascript implementation, just like SpiderMonkey is Mozilla’s implementation, or V8 is Google’s implementation.  Any code not referencing the browser DOM will work identically across those engines.

Comment: @sw you're correct, it's a bug. I'll report on Meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say in what environment you're working.  If you mean [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a [Windows Scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950396.aspx) environment, then you can use the [`Scripting.FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
if (fso.FileExists(path)) {
    WScript.Echo("It's a file!");
} else if (fso.FolderExists(path)) {
    WScript.Echo("It's a folder!");
} else {
    WScript.Echo("It's superman!");
}
```

Comment: I didn't knew this is the way solving it, guess I'm lazy looking around. +1 for feeding my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript alone I know you cant. But you can do some validation with a file if you know its extension. Here look an example.

**JS**

```
var pathX = "[?:[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+(?:.txt|.sql)"; /* File validation using extension*/

function testRegx(frm){
    var path = frm.testfile.value;

    if(path.toString().match(pathX)){
        alert("Valid");
    } else {
        alert("Invalid");
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="testupload">
    <p>
    <input type="file" name="testfile">
    <input type="button" onClick="testRegx(this.form);" value="test">
    </p>
</form>
```

This techniques still not the best way as in you can tampered a file to change its extension or you can rename a file by adding a valid extension base on the given valid file.

Comment: can the tampering be possible in windows? ie. can a file(without extension) and folder be of same name? I guess not

Comment: @sw you can change the extension and also remove the extension, but of course the format of the file is still the original I guess. You cant for a folder with same name and parent.